# Повторения данных в массиве PHP

Tags: массивы, php, sql, mysql

Доброго времени суток господа, подскажите:

Есть массив `$mesto` и уникальный массив `$unic_mesto = array_unique($mesto);`
Как узнать сколько раз каждое значение `$unic_mesto` повторяеся в `$mesto`.

А смысл такой: есть график заездов на парковочные места 
(места назывются: 1A,1B,1C,2A,2B,2C,3A,3B,3C,1A,2B,2B,3C,3C,1A,1A,1A,3A,1A ...) как узнать какое самое популярное?

**P.S. Если бы достать запросом в мускул было бы вообще идеально, колонка '`mesto`' в таблице '`tab1`'**

Comment: а это в базе хранятся данные ? может из нее самое популярное сразу и достать ?

Comment: Да, это столбец 'mesto'. Если бы достать запросом в мускул было бы вообще идеально.

Comment: arsort ($mesto, SORT_NUMERIC);

foreach ($all_mesto as $key => $value) {
echo "$value машин на место: $key<br>";
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(mesto) AS cnt
FROM tab1
GROUP BY mesto
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Это если одним запросом.

Вот только COUNT с GROUP'ом и ORDER'ом будут не быстро работать, но чувство такое, что скорость все равно будет намного выше скорости PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Может эта функция Вам поможет - [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). Потом только отсортировать нужно будет.